# How to return Go byte array when calling webassembly code in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, vector, webassembly

I want to calculate the Fibonacci sequence result. Here is my Rust code which will return the series of a given number.

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn fibonacci(n: usize) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut x = vec![1, 1];
    for i in 2..n {
        let next_x = x[i - 1] + x[i - 2];
        x.push(next_x)
    }
    x
}
```

The result from cargo run `[1, 1, 2]`
When I call this code in go-ext-wasmer, I'm getting the invalid output.

```
    bytes, _ := wasm.ReadBytes("fib.wasm")
    instance, _ := wasm.NewInstance(bytes)
    defer instance.Close()
    randoms, err := instance.Exports["fibonacci"](3, 0)

    resp := randoms.ToI32()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error", err)
    }
    memory = instance.Memory.Data()
    fmt.Println("fibonacci:", memory[resp:resp+10])
```

Result from go `fibonacci: [10 0 0 144 0 17 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0]`

How do I get the correct return from go? I wanted a series which should be in []byte form

Comment: Use an array instead of a vector.  I'm not familiar with Go and Rust but it looks like you're trying to read the byes of a vector directly, which may be impossible if it's not POD (Plain Old Data), which a vector is not.  At least in C++.